# How do I save an object to AWS DynamoDB from Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I'm creating a mobile applications that allows users to login via facebook using AWS Cognito. The code that handles that looks something like this.

```
public async Task FacebookCongitoLogin(FacebookProfile profile)
{

        config = new AmazonCognitoSyncConfig { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1 };
        creds = new CognitoAWSCredentials("ARN_ID_STUFF", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        creds.AddLogin("graph.facebook.com", MySettings.FBToken);

        syncManager = new CognitoSyncManager(creds, config);

        await creds.GetCredentialsAsync();

        Content = null;
        saveProfileInfo(profile);
 }

private void saveProfileInfo(FacebookProfile profile)
{
    Dataset profileData = syncManager.OpenOrCreateDataset("fb_profile");
                profileData.OnSyncSuccess += SyncSuccessCallback;
                profileData.OnSyncFailure += SyncFailureCallback;
    profileData.Put("fb_profile",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(profile));
                profileData.SynchronizeAsync();
}
```

After I get the user logged in I'm trying to safe an object to my newly created DynamoDB Table like so.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentity;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel;

namespace TechPact
{
    public class CreateInviteAction
    {
        private CognitoAWSCredentials creds;
        public CreateInviteAction()
        {
            var token = TechPactSettings.FBToken;
            creds = new CognitoAWSCredentials("ARN_ID_KEY", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            creds.AddLogin("graph.facebook.com", token);
            creds.GetCachedCredentials();

        }

        public async Task execute(Invite invite)
        {
            var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(creds, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            var context = new DynamoDBContext(client);

            await context.SaveAsync(invite);

        }
    }
}
```

When the action above runs I get an AmazonDynamoDBException `User:arn:aws:sts::123234234:assumedrole/inviteapp_auth_MOBILEHUB_1232342345/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to preform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-ease-1:1232314234:table/Invite`

here is the custom role police that I created for the user pool.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:12312312312:table/invite-mobilehub-234234234-Invite"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${graph.facebook.com:id}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the IAM roles linked to this pool? They would've been auto created upon creating the identity pool. By that message, it looks like you need to add dynamodb:DescribeTable to your auth role.

Comment: @JeffBailey added the role above that I generated from the Congnito role generator. I did change some of the numbers of the dynamodb arn for this post but everything else is as I have it in the user pool role policy

Comment: The resource in that role looks screwy. It should be 'arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<account id>:table/<table name>, which by your error message means it has the table name wrong.

Comment: Are you thinking it should be something like arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:12312312312:table/Invite

Comment: Yes, give that a go. As an aside/for future people who find this question, a former Cognito team member wrote this excellent blog on the subject: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies/